# Recommended workflow/best practice for setting up Virtual env within Vagrant

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, vagrant

I am following the getting started with Django tutorial and managed to finish the 1st project but when I re-entered Vagrant SSH all packages i installed on my vagrant shared folder and my virtual environment were gone.

Whats is best practice for setting up a development environment once in Vagrant SSH?

Currently i have done:
1) Vagrant SSH
2) Installed default python packages (pip, dev, git, etc.)
3) Install Virtual env
4) CD to shared folder (ie /vagrant)
5) Create virtual env ( 'virtualenv env_name')
6) Source virtual env (source env_name/bin/activate)
7) Install Virtual env pkgs (ie. Django, pyscho2, etc.)

Once im done for the day:

8) deactivate virtual env
9) exit out of ssh
10) vagrant halt

Is this generally the correct workflow?  I'm confused about step 5 in particular.  Is this the correct way to create the virtual env or should I default to a different folder (the tutorial starts the folder with '~/')?.  Am i'm shutting things down properly?

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks in advance!

Edit: I just noticed that virtual box has several different version of my precise box.  This might be whats causing the missing Envs and packages that ive already installed.  It seems like im doing something wrong spinnng up the vagrant instance.

Answer (score 1):

Using virtualenv with Vagrant in the gswd tutorial is slightly more tricky than normal virtual env work because of where the virutal environment is stored.

Here is an example where I create 1 virutalenv on Vagrant, deactivate it and create a 2nd virtual env:

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects$* virtualenv ~/blog-venv1
```

**-- note that in the above line we are passing a path to the virtual env**

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects$* source ~/blog-venv1/bin/activate
(blog-venv1)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects/$* deactivate
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects$* virtualenv ~/blog-venv2
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects2$* source ~/blog-venv2/bin/activate
```